# Git merge 2 branches - changes missing

Tags: git, git-merge

I had branch foo. I branched it and called new branch bar.
Since they are both very similar in purpose, I refactored a bunch of classes in bar instead of creating them anew.
Now I want a branch that has both foo and bar. Merging them ends up in the result looking like foo. I guess that makes sense to git. What can I do though?